# Heroku and Rails: App pushes successfully but nothing appears in heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to learn how to push to Heroku. I created a brand new Rails app using postgresql

```
rails new p3 -d postgresql
```

and followed all instructions exactly as they are on [herokus help page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#deploy-your-application-to-heroku).

```
git init
heroku create
git add .
git commit -m "rails new p3 -d postgresql"
git push heroku master
run rake db:migrate
```

When I perform the `heroku open`command it directs me to a page that says *"The page you were looking for doesn't exist"*. Furthermore, When  I check my code under *heroku personal apps*, the app name shows up but none of the code appears.

I have no idea what to do next. What do I do when my code pushes successfully, but nothing appears in my heroku app?

EDIT:

Activity feed shows I am pushing, but still nothing changed in code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After checking my logs by typing `heroku logs --tail` I realized I was receiving an error message because my routes were not setup. Setup a basic get *'/'* route and it will work correctly.